# Definition of a limit point

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, derivatives

I'm reviewing a book on calculus which describes the definition of a *limit point* like this:

> A limit point, point of accumulation, or cluster point of a set of
>   numbers is a number *l* such that every deleted δ neighborhood of *l*
>   contains members of the set; that is, no matter how small the radius
>   of a ball about *l*, there are points of the set within it. In other
>   words, for any δ > 0, however small, we can always find a member x of
>   the set which is not equal to *l* but which is such that ⏐x – *l*⏐ < δ. By
>   considering smaller and smaller values of δ, we see that there must be
>   infinitely many such values of x.

I did a lot of thermodynamics back at uni so went into calculus in quite a bit of depth. I can't remember when and how I learned the definition of a limit considering it's a very intuitive concept. However, wouldn't a straight line satisfy the above equation with a limit being any other straight line? You can always pick a point on the limit line and draw a circle of radius δ (not saying δ is small) which will contain a subset of the other line?

Note that when the definition says small, I take it as *different size*.

Comment: I do not fully understand what you are saying. Be aware that there are two objects here: a set and a point. The question then is: "is this point a limit point of this set?" The definition gives the criteria for this. In what you bring forward about straight lines what is the set you are thinking of and what is the point?

Comment: Not clear… The above def consider the *real* line where every point on iy is a real number. See [Limit point (or cluster point or accumulation point)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point).

Comment: Are you thinking of lines in the plane as "points" ?

Comment: No, I'm thinking of a line on the plane as a set. Then any point x from this set, can be less than δ from a limit l. @drhab - slightly edited the last bit to make it clearer.

Comment: The precise def is "for any $δ > 0$; the "however small" is only for intution, but is formally useless: "however" means *however* : big **and** small.

Comment: In math, the words "any" and "every" are inter-changeable.  By saying "for **any** $\delta>0$, the ball of radius $\delta$ about $l$ will have points distinct from $l$ that intersect the set" it means the same as "for **every** $\delta>0$, the ball of radius $\delta$ about $l$ will have points distinct from $l$ that intersect the set."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I edited the last bit to make it clearer of what's in my head. That's right, I'm not taking "small" directly - by "small" I understand of different size (bigger or smaller) which is why I am wondering - for any 2 lines, one would be a limit to the other.

Comment: Two lines can be looked at as two sets or as two points. In both cases we do not have a set and a point (as required in this context).

Comment: I don't see how you can make any claims about two lines that are related to this problem.  This is a definition of  "limit point" (there is no such thing as a "limit line").  I'm not sure how two parallel lines that never meet could be viewed as "limit lines" of each other anyway, assuming one had some definition of "limit line."  The limit points of the subset of $\mathbb{R}$ given by the interval $(0,1)$ are all points in the interval $[0,1]$. A set is "closed" if it contains its limit points, so, $[0,1]$ is a closed set.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, every point of a straight line is a limit point of the same straight line which makes the straight line a closed subset of $\mathbb {R^2}$

If what  you are saying is that every point of the plane is the limit point of some line passing through that point you are  is correct.  Also every point of the plane is a limit point of the plane.

The concept of limit point is somehow related to the definition of limit of a sequence.

If you have a point say $x_0$  which is the limit of a sequence of distinct points of a set $A$, then $x_0$ is a limit point of $A$

Answer (score 0):

No you can not. Consider the line $y=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. If we take $\delta=\frac{1}{2}$ we find that the ball
$$B_{\frac{1}{2}}((1,1)=\{(x_{1},x_{2})\in\mathbb{R}^{2}:\sqrt{(1-x_{1})^{2}+(1-x^{2})^{2}}<\frac{1}{2}\}$$
does not contain any point of the line. This is easy to verify, let $(x,0)$ be a point on the line, then $$\sqrt{(1-x)^{2}+(1-0)^{2}}\geq \sqrt{1}=1>\frac{1}{2},$$
so $(x,0)\not\in B_{\frac{1}{2}}((1,1))$.